# Adding a condition in an AWS policy using the name of the CloudFormation stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a policy for a user on AWS so that it can do whatever it want with stacks that have a stack name containing `foo`. I have looked at the documentation and found information about the `Condition` value but I did not find how to use the name of the stack in it.

My policy currently looks like that:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "private value",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "I do not know what to write here": "foo"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The AWS documentation is hard to use, I know what I should do if I was working with [s3 buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html) but not for CloudFormation stacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Condition is not needed here. You can simply set the right resource.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "private value",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack/foo-*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Let me know if this helps ;)

Comment: I do not have an exact stack name, I only know that the resources will contain a distinctive element `foo` but it can be two different resources `foo-bar-hello` or `foo-bar-goodbye`.

Comment: I edited my response, it should be ok now.I tested myself and it seems to work.